# Merge Contents of 2 Directories with nginx

Tags: web, nginx, url-rewriting, assets

I have

- /site/app/assets/css
- /site/app/assets/js
- /site/public/assets/img
- /site/public/assets/whatever

The web root should be /site/public

I would like a request to http://example.com/assets/img to go to /site/public/assets/img (like default) but I would also like a request to http://example.com/assets/js to go to /site/app/assets/js .

The reason behind doing this is so that the production server can then process the sources in the app folder, put them in a different folder local to the production server only (out of version control), and then on the server the folder containing the processed assets would be merged in instead.

I'm thinking there must be a way but I can't figure it out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the alternative `root` for desired locations. Like this.

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    root /var/www/site/public;

    location ~ /assets/(css|js)/ {
      root /var/www/site/app;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks I can see that would work in this case but do you know what the solution would be if the folder in the app folder wasn't called assets, or the url had more levels like example.com/something/somethingelse/assets ?

Comment: If the app directory has a directory with assets but it's named differently, and you still want to address it with the same URL, you would need to use [``alias``](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#alias) instead. It'll let you "replace" URL segments. If assets directory is contained in another directory you would just need to adjust your root in the location, like, ``root /var/www/site/app/something/something;`` so a path that matches location regex in conjunction with the root corresponds to a file name.